# .htaccess routing strange behavior

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am having a little difficulty with rewriting of a url using the .htaccess

I'm trying to make the page https://example.com/foo/ point out to https://example.com/bar/ without changing the url (meaning that the url should stay: https://example.com/foo/)

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo(/.*|)$ /bar$1 [PT,L,NC]
```

This seems to work for all cases but one: when i access the page https://example.com/foo (I automatically get redirected to https://example.com/foo/ , and get to see the content of the page https://example.com/bar this works as it should) then when I remove the '/' from the end of the url (the url i'm accessing is again https://example.com/foo) my url this time changes to https://example.com/bar/.

The htaccess file doesn't have anything else written to it.

Edit: I have also noticed that the rewrite rule works as it should when redirecting to https. (Thats why it works when i type in example.com/foo)

Comment: Are `foo` and `bar` real directories?

Comment: `Foo` doesn't exist, `bar` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small Correction

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo(.*)$ bar/$1 [L]
```

Should solve the problem

Comment: Tried that didn't work, I have also noticed that the rewrite rule works as it should when redirecting to https, if it doesn't have to redirect it doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me, Can you see if what I'm doing is right scenario My files are here --https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byqr9WL_JfnHMUdsSW9ZNlY3SlU/view?usp=sharing